# Blueimp file upload plugin slower on Windows client browsers

Tags: jquery, file, upload, blueimp

My web site uses the Blueimp Jquery file upload plugin, and runs on a CentOS 6 server (using the PHP handler).
The site is only accessed on our internal network (clients are 1gbps to the desktop).

Consistently, upload speeds are far slower on Windows, regardless of browser:  IE, Chrome, Firefox etc.

Upload speeds average around 50mbps on a 200mb test file (TIFF image).
However, on Mac OS X clients, regardless of browser, speeds average at around 300mbps with the same file, which is considerably faster.

The test machines are on the same network and subnet etc.
Can anyone suggest how to troubleshoot this, or which BlueImp settings may be affecting the upload speeds only on Windows?

Does the OS or Windows based browsers handle chunked file uploads in a different way, that may require a settings tweak?

TIA for any suggestions.

Comment: Does everyone have blueimp uploader working just as fast on Windows machines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do they both have HDDs/SSDs? Otherwise it might be a difference in read speed.

If they do, maybe you could check Windows' Resource Monitor and see what is using up bandwidth.

Source: https://superuser.com/questions/424958/slow-upload-speed-on-windows-compare-to-mac

If that's not the problem, maybe it is an issue with the wireless adapter (assuming they use wireless).

It may be a blueimp problem, but it doesn't look like there is any platform-specific code in the source.

Comment: Hey, thanks for that.  The Windows machine is on a 1gbps ethernet connection, but it's running on a VM (bridged network with the mac), so I'd expect it to be a little slower due to a little over head.  Although I'd investigated networking a lot, I'd not noticed that CPU was actually causing the bottle neck.  After spotting this in Windows Resource Manager, I allocated more cores to my VM, and things are much closer to mac speeds (77 seconds on OS X, 97 seconds on Win7 VM for 2.8gb file).  My other test machine was a laptop running Win 7 natively, but I'll look closer at the CPU on there now.